# Spinner until PHP parse somesing

Tags: javascript, php

in my PHP ,  I am parsing Json  links, I am searching for too much times for script wich is going to show the loader until parsing done. 
example :

```
<?php

     echo " spinner here" ; 

     sleep(5);//lets say this is parsing json script

?>
```

I tried so much thing and didnt worked, please help.

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend using AJAX to make the call to the long running process, and use JS to display a spinner on start, and remove it when the request returns a response. I think this is a pretty common pattern to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with Ajax, this is how it works : the HTML code has a button, when clicked it starts the "spinner" and call the PHP parsing code, when the PHP parsing code finishes, it returns to Ajax and the spinner stops :

**spinner.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function myAjax ()
{ $("#my_div").html( "Wait while parsing..." );      // START SPINNER.
  $.ajax( { type    : 'POST',
            url     : 'spinner.php',                 // CALL PHP CODE.
            success : function ( result )
                      { $("#my_div").html( result ); // STOP SPINNER.
                      },
            error   : function ( xhr )
                      { alert( "error" );
                      }
          }
        );
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="myAjax()">Parse JSON links</button>
    <div id="my_div"></div>                         <!-- YOUR SPINNER HERE -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**spinner.php**

```
<?php
sleep( 5 );
echo "Parsing finished!";
?>
```

Just create two files with the given names, copy-paste these codes and run!

Comment: can I call PHP on same url that we do html?  is there any possibility?

Comment: @Mr.Samxo, do you mean `url : 'www.mywebsite.com/spinner.php'`? Yes, you can do it.

Comment: I mean I want to do ajax and php at same folder, like Index.php  I won't use 2 file

Comment: Well, yes, you can do it, but I'm not sure it's a good idea. Give me a minute to test it, I'll be right back.

Comment: @Mr.Samxo, I'm back. The ajax doesn't work, maybe because it's not PHP only, files must be separated. So, doesn't my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do it in php, then take a look at [`flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) and [`ob_flush`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php)

I had to call them twice in a row to get it to work.

```
<?php

echo "spinner here..." ; 

flush();
ob_flush();
flush();
ob_flush();

sleep(5);//lets say this is parsing json script

echo "done!";
```

Comment: it works on my locall,  but it does not works on hosting server